# How to denote a set of exponents for a polynomial expression?

Tags: polynomials, notation, set-theory

I'm finding it difficult to use proper set notation and I need help making the notation more simplified and readable.

#### What I'm trying to do

I am trying to define a $d$-order polynomial function $f^d=f^d(\alpha, \beta; \theta)$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the two dimensions of the function and $\theta$ is a vector of coefficients. What I find challenging is defining the structure of the polynomial depending on the order $d$. I need the notation to resolve to:

- $f^1(\alpha, \beta; \theta) = \theta_0 + \theta_1 \alpha + \theta_2 \beta$
- $f^2(\alpha, \beta; \theta) = \theta_0 + \theta_1 \alpha + \theta_2 \beta + \theta_3 \alpha \beta+ \theta_4 \alpha^2 + \theta_5 \beta^2$
- $\vdots$
- $f^d(\alpha, \beta; \theta)$ = ??

#### What I have so far

What I have come up with so far is the following:

Let $\mathcal{P}^d$ be the set of exponent tuples $(a, b)$, such that:

$$
\mathcal{P}^d = \left\{ (a, b) ~|~ a, b \in \{0,..., d\}, a + b \leq d \right\}
$$

Then,

$$
f^d(\alpha, \beta; \theta) = \sum_{i=0}^{|\mathcal{P^d}|} \theta_i \cdot \alpha^{a_i} \cdot\beta^{b_i} \quad \text{for each } (a_i, b_i) \in \mathcal{P}^d
$$

Where the coefficient vector is $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^{|\mathcal{P}^d|}$ and $(a_i, b_i)$ is the exponent tuple of the $i$th term.

Even though it sort-of works, I find this notation somewhat cumbersome and hard to understand.

I checked if it works for $d=1, 2$. For example:

- $\mathcal{P}^1 = \{(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)\}$ and therefore $f^1(\alpha, \beta; \theta) = \theta_0 \alpha^0 \beta^0 + \theta_1 \alpha^1 \beta^0 + \theta_2 \alpha^0 \beta^1$
- $\mathcal{P}^2 = \{(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (0, 2)\}$

#### My questions

- How do I simplify the definition of $f^d$ in terms of notation?
- What is a standard way to write this kind of polynomial?
- Is there a way I can omit having to define $\mathcal{P}^d$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use double indices? $$f^d(\alpha,\beta; \theta) = \sum_{i=0}^d \sum_{j=0}^{d-i} \theta_{i,j} \alpha^i \beta^j $$

Comment: This formula doesn't quite work because some exponents are missing. For example for $d=1$ we get:

$f^1(\alpha, \beta; \theta) = \sum_{i=0}^{1} \sum_{j=0}^{0} \theta_{i, j} \alpha^i \beta^j = 
\theta_{0, 0} \alpha^0 \beta^0 + \theta_{1, 0} \alpha^1 \beta^0 = \theta_{0,0}+\theta_{1,0} \alpha$

Which is only two terms instead of 3. The term with $\beta$ is missing.

Comment: The correct formula is $$f^d(\alpha,\beta;\theta)=\sum_{i=0}^d\sum_{j=0}^i\theta_{i,j}\alpha^{i-j}\beta^j$$You want the powers of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ at each $i$ to add up to $i$.

Comment: @Speterius No, for $d=1$ it's $\sum_{i=0}^1 \sum_{j=0}^{1-i}$.  So for $i=0$ you get $j=0$ and $j=1$, for $i=1$ you get $j=0$, resulting in all three desired terms.

Comment: @Andrei That's another correct way to organize it.  Your $i-j$ is my $i$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Indeed. I should have paid more attention

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes you are right. I overlooked the fact that $d-i$ changes for each "outer loop" iteration.